# Equivalent of Python's List Comprehension in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, list-comprehension

Consider the following JSON representation of an array:

```
logMessages = [
   {
      "timestamp":1499776056977,
      "message":"Log message c7a09226",
      "ingestionTime":1499776058327
   },
   {
      "timestamp":1499777056977,
      "message":"Log message e5d5b51a3ae1",
      "ingestionTime":1499777058327
   },
   {
      "timestamp":1499778056977,
      "message":"Log message b79f4620935b",
      "ingestionTime":1499778058327
   }
]
```

Suppose that I'd like to keep only `timestamp` and `message` and omit `ingestionTime`. In Python, I would do:

```
>>> [ {'timestamp': o['timestamp'], 'message': o['message']} for o in logMessages]

[{'timestamp': 1499776056977, 'message': 'Log message c7a09226'},
 {'timestamp': 1499777056977, 'message': 'Log message e5d5b51a3ae1'}, 
 {'timestamp': 1499778056977, 'message': 'Log message b79f4620935b'}]
```

How do I do the same field filtering in Javascript?

Comment: It's just a simple `map` function, there are plenty similar or even identical questions :(

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I wanted to present the translation between Python's list comprehension and the Javascript equivalent. I think it bears value to Python developers trying to write their first JS code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use object destructuring to obtain a subset of keys.

```
> logMessages= [ 
  { timestamp: 1499776056977,
    message: 'Log message c7a09226',
    ingestionTime: 1499776058327 },
  { timestamp: 1499777056977,
    message: 'Log message e5d5b51a3ae1',
    ingestionTime: 1499777058327 },
  { timestamp: 1499778056977,
    message: 'Log message b79f4620935b',
    ingestionTime: 1499778058327 } ]

> logMessages.map(({ timestamp, message }) => ({ timestamp, message }));

[ { timestamp: 1499776056977, message: 'Log message c7a09226' },
  { timestamp: 1499777056977,
    message: 'Log message e5d5b51a3ae1' },
  { timestamp: 1499778056977,
    message: 'Log message b79f4620935b' } ]
```

Documentation for Destructuring assignment syntax can be found:

- [Mozilla Develoepr Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Would you care to elaborate and add a reference link please?

Comment: Why is it that putting parentheses around the return value works, whereas just using braces without the parens doesn't return the expected value? This seems like a strange quirk of JS.

Answer (score 4):

[`.map` with an arrow function does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the trick:

```
logMessages= [ 
  { timestamp: 1499776056977,
    message: 'Log message c7a09226',
    ingestionTime: 1499776058327 },
  { timestamp: 1499777056977,
    message: 'Log message e5d5b51a3ae1',
    ingestionTime: 1499777058327 },
  { timestamp: 1499778056977,
    message: 'Log message b79f4620935b',
    ingestionTime: 1499778058327 } ]

> logMessages.map( (o) => {return {timestamp: o.timestamp, message: o.message}})
[ { timestamp: 1499776056977, message: 'Log message c7a09226' },
  { timestamp: 1499777056977,
    message: 'Log message e5d5b51a3ae1' },
  { timestamp: 1499778056977,
    message: 'Log message b79f4620935b' } ]
```

Comment: Works, but Jack's answer is more elegant.